# Python while loop isn't doing what it's supposed to

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

All the variables that aren't local are at the top of the code under the modules.
I'm using multithreading to use multiple functions to use at the same time, and even when comparing it to the other loops I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

```
def SQUIRE():
global currency
global alive
global squire
while alive == True and squire == True:
    chanceA = random.randint(1, 100)
    if chanceA <= 10:
        currency += 10
        print("You have delivered a message for 10 currency. You now own", currency, " currency.")
        time.sleep(1)
```

It's supposed to check if man() alive = True and if squire = true, pick a random number between 1 and 100. If that number is between 1 and 10, add 10 to currency. 
Instead it is doing absolutely nothing.

https://pastebin.com/twxNmeDF

Here is the full code for reference.
It's probably a terrible mess, it's just a side thing I'm working on while I learn Python. Only been at it a few days

Comment: If you're just learning Python, you certainly shouldn't be messing about with threads. (In fact that goes for if you're an expert, too...)

Comment: Do you really want all these things to happen atg the same time? Could you do one step at a time (maybe yield will help)

Answer (score 1):

What seem to happen is that `squire` is `False` and therefore the loop doesn't execute.

When working with threads you should be aware that there in general is no guarantee that the threads will execute in certain order, they are effectively run in parallell and it may happen that the `SQUIRE` thread gets to the test of the `squire` variable before any other thread have been able to change it to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using multiple threads you should wait for each thread in threadpool to finish accessing the resources. Hence, you should use `t.join()` after you start the thread.